# rest assured test failing intermittently due to data missing in the response

Tags: java, postman, rest-assured

I have a rest assured test where I am converting the json into the java object and asserting on the java object.In the response object there is a particular value that I am asserting on in the test. When I run the service manually using POSTMAN I always see the parameter value in the response but when my automation tests execute the value is not always present in the response object.

I am suspecting it can be the issue from the service side not sending the consistent response but when hit manually the value is always present.

Test code:

```
    @Test
    public void validateResponse() {

        RequestObject.name= "Hello";
        RequestObject.age="20";          

        ResponseObject responseObject= given()
                .contentType(TestData.CONTENT_TYPE_FOR_TEST)
                .body(RequestObject)
                .then()
                .log()
                .everything()
                .when()
                .post(uri)
                .as(ResponseObject.class);    
        assertNotNull(responseObject.name);
        assertNotNull(responseObject.year.age);
```

I think my test is simple not complicated but the assertion fails intermittently.

Any insight of how to debug more on this?

Answer (score 1):

Your fields in `RequestObject` looks static and I think it's quite likely the JSON object mapper won't bind the result to static fields. Try make them non-static.